# how to add the previous values using subquery in Oracle

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I have a scenario to add a all previous values ...

Input is this of a column of a table

```
Col
3
5
4
6
9
7
8
```

And I need output in this manner:

```
Col      Col2
3         3
5         8
4         12
6         18 
9         27
7         34
8         42
```

Kindly reply asap

Regards,
Neeraj

Comment: Do you have a column to order by? If not, there's no guarantee that `Col` will always be selected in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a field to order by, you can use `SUM ... OVER` to do the running sum;

```
SELECT Col, SUM(Col) OVER (ORDER BY id) Col2
FROM Table1
ORDER BY id;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15988/1).